# update the date within the url of a csv, prior to downloading it

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby script that downloads a csv file with an embedded date i.e.

`File.write("directory/my.csv",Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("https://exampleurl.csv2017-06-26")))`

*the actual url is very long.

I want to run that code **weekly** to update the data, but the date of the download is embedded within the URL.

How can I split the url, update the date, and join it back together, prior to running the code?

Answer (score 0):

Use substitute:

```
a = s.sub(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/,"2017-01-01")
```

or split:

```
s="abc2017-10-10def"
a = s.split(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/)
url = a[0]+"2017-11-10"+a[1]
```

If the date is only at the end, use:

```
url = a[0]+"2017-11-10"
```

Comment: Might be less messy to use `sub`.